# ReactJS apply multiple inline styles

Tags: react-native, reactjs

Let's say I have the following styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
padding: {
  padding: 10
},
margin: {
  margin: 10
}
});
```

and I want to apply both of them to a react component?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do/what you don't get how to do.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

While I did some research for this, the answer is not inmediatly clear, one suggestion is:

```
<View style={Object.assign({}, styles.padding, styles.margin)}>
    ...
</View>
```

Object.assign() takes the list of arguments and merges them, however, if you don't pass the first empty object it will overwrite the first argument, so if you want to keep you styles clean you have to pass it.

However as of react 0.27.2 I got an asign error trying to do this.

Some further reading revealed:

```
<View style={StyleSheet.flatten([styles.postHeader, styles.flowRight])}>
  ...
</View>
```

Works just fine, but this is very verbose and not really intuitive, after I while I found another snippet:

```
<View style={[styles.postHeader, styles.flowRight]}>
```

For all intents and purposes this was what I was looking for.

I just thought of sharing this knowledge here since it seems fairly obvious but I could not find any documentation for it.

Comment: as of most recent React web version Nov. 2020, your first solution works for me. Legend!

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution I use it in inline css

```
 <div style={{color: "yellow", fontSize: 24}}>Style Me</div>
```

or use by adding classes as

```
 <div className="section-spac banner-with-whitebg">Style Me</div>
```